# Printing in 4.2 SDK - would like to support 4.0 without app crashing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, printing, crash, airprint

I'm trying to have printing in my application.

While this works, and I can indeed print from my application, I would like to be able to run my application on devices that aren't running iOS 4.2.

Even if I check the version before I run the code.

The method that prints the document has all of the classes that are being used to print.

Whenever I switch the simulator back to 4.1, I get a Symbol not found exception that displays the error:

dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter
  Referenced from: /Users/Jack/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.1/Applications/794534DB-DB53-42E7-A294-7E78FDD3899B/Documentation.app/Documentation
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
 in /Users/Jack/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.1/Applications/794534DB-DB53-42E7-A294-7E78FDD3899B/Documentation.app/Documentation

I don't want to discard the users who haven't upgraded to 4.2.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which compiler are you using? If you haven't, you should switch to LLVM GCC or LLVM to support automatic weak linking as described by Marco Arment in [Supporting older versions of iOS while using new APIs](http://www.marco.org/1648550153).